# Is there any way to make an user id as a key in a python dictionary with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to set a variable separated from each user, for example:
User a: money: 400
User b: money: 300

But I'm trying to make the User a User b thingy the user id, I've already tried

```
if message.content.startswith('!info'):
  if message.author.id in data:
    print('true')
  else:
    print('false')
    with open('data.json', 'r+') as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      data[str(message.author.id)]['money'] += 300
      file.seek(0)
      json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

But I got an error: "KeyError: {my user id}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `KeyError` means that your user id isn't even in the dictionary in the first place. Try doing this to fix it:

JSON file:

```json
{
    "<user_a_id>": {
        "money": 0                      
    },
    "<user_b_id>" : {
        "money": 0
    }
}
```

Python file:

```py
with open('users.json', 'r+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data[str(message.author.id)] = {"money": 0}
    data[str(message.author.id)]['money'] += 300
    
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

also, `author.id` is an `int` so you would have to convert it into an `str` for it to properly work.

Comment: I mean I want to add a key everytime a new user is not in the dictionary, I tried to add a key with data[str(message.author.id)]['money'] but it's the same

Comment: can you show me what `data` was defined as and did you do anything to `data` like removing keys and stuff like that

Comment: data is a json.load variable I'm gonna show you the data: {'test': 1}

Comment: that's all of it? it doesn't even have `money` or `user id` or even 
 nested dictionary.

Comment: yeah that's all of it, what I'm trying to say is that if a user is not on the dictionary I wanna add a new key, with nested dictionary, and I've tried your solution, and i've already tried your solution, but I got a KeyError again

Comment: @heagan Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65820190/edit) your answer to include the actual code that you're running.

Comment: @heagan Thank you. `data[str(message.author.id)]['money'] += 300` is your problem. You can't use `+=` if the key doesn't already exist; that's why you're getting a `KeyError`. That line should be in your true branch.

Comment: ahh ok, so I should check if the key exists or not, if not then we uses the = sign?

Comment: @heagan try this code it should work, if you get a file not found error, replace `'users.json'` to `'<file-name>/users.json'`. I just tested it, it works

Comment: how do I close a question? I'm new to this

Comment: @heagan it should be near the `edit` button

Comment: ok, this is getting a bit off topic, but when I press delete question, it says you can't delete a question that others have put time to it

Comment: hmm ok then just close the question